# Android DialogueFragment setting up custom layout

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I am a beginner in android development.For the application I am developing, I need a dialoge fragment with layout as specified in a xml file in res/layout.How can I achieve this.I have seen many tutorials online,but unfortunately most of them explains how to build a dialogue with yes/no buttons.But my requirement is a custom layout for DialogFragment.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple custom class and extends the  dialog fragment as below. You can create your own layout and handle the view clicks.

```
public static class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_fragment, container, false);
    return view
 }
}
```